# window.GLOBALS[17] is null in the new Gmail UI while it is present for the old Gmail UI

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I have a Chrome extension which uses a library called [gmail.js](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js) which is sort of dependent on the window.GLOBALS[17] object from the Gmail window however in the new UI of gmail, Gmail seems to have removed the GLOBALS[17] which is equal to null now, Now I have no way to access the data that was present inside the GLOBALS[17] object, I have searched, looked and tried everything but do not seem to have an alternative to GLOBALS[17] object

The GLOBALS[17] is still available on the old Gmail UI

[image: When seen in old Gmail UI]

And is null in new Gmail UI

[image: Wheen seen from new Gmail UI]

Without this I cannot know vital information like whether the email is in conversation view and so on

Why was this removed? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.GLOBALS[69] will reflect "Conversation View" setting for gmail that makes it the alternative for window.GLOBALS[17].

checkout [Shashikaran's](https://github.com/shashikiran-im) Comment on the corresponding [github issue](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/issues/485)

Answer (score 0):

I have maintained for many years a Chrome extension for a client that extends Gmail functionality with the functionality of S/MIME support using crypto smartcards. In the old Gmail UI, we had taken lots of information from GLOBAL[17], including:

- ike parameter
- is mailbox delegated switch
- delegated emails
- language of the UI
- email signature switch (switched on/off)
- email signature - appended at the end of all outgoing messages

All of the above information can be found elsewhere in GLOBALS or in Gmail DOM. However I had a problem to locate the information about the signature and email signature switch (in the old UI, it was in GLOBALS[17][4][1], properties sx_mrsp_*, bx_se). I noticed the new Gmail UI downloads this information from a page that contains some JavaScript *_GM_setData* with a JSON parameter, that contains very similar information like GLOBALS. The section in the downloaded data starts with a string *'_GM_setData({"w43KIf":["sdpc"..'*.  Maybe this JSON might be used as a complete replacement of GLOBALS. Here is the snippet of JS code I implemented for this purpose - if you are solving similar issues, you can use it for an inspiration (the code requires JQuery and any implementation of sprintf):

```
console.log(
        "Going to download Gmail config to check for signature and signature switch.");
$.ajax(sprintf(
        "https://mail.google.com/mail/ca/u/0/?ui=2&ik=%s&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1",
        gmailConfig_ike), {
    "type": "GET",
    "accept": "html",
    "error": function (response,
                       statusText1,
                       jqXHR1)
    {
        console.log("error getting config data (signature will be unavailable)):" + statusText1);
        sendResponse(false);
    },
    "success": function (response,
                         statusText1,
                         jqXHR1)
    {
        // console.log("Data obtained: " + response);

        var dom = $(response);

        dom.filter('script').each(function ()
        {
            var myscript = this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || '';
            // console.log("script:  " + myscript);
            if (myscript.indexOf('["bx_se"') !== -1) {
                console.log("bx_se found.");

                //console.log(myscript);
                var startToken = '_GM_setData({"';
                var endToken = '"}); ';
                var subscript = myscript.substring(myscript.indexOf(startToken) + startToken.length - 2);
                // console.log("subscript: " + subscript);
                var finalJSONString = subscript.substring(0,
                        subscript.indexOf(endToken) + 2);
                // console.log("finalJSONString: " + finalJSONString);
                var finalJSON = JSON.parse(finalJSONString);
                //console.log(finalJSON);

                // this locates the interesting information in the JSON object
                var configArr = finalJSON.sBEv4c[2][1];
                // console.log(configArr);

                for (var k = 0; k < configArr.length; k++) {
                    var param = configArr[k];
                    if (param && param[0].indexOf("sx_mrsp_") == 0) {
                        console.log("Signature located: " + param[1]);
                        gmailConfig_signature = param[1];
                    }
                    if (param && param[0].indexOf("bx_se") == 0) {
                        console.log("Signature switch located: " + param[1]);
                        gmailConfig_signSwitch = param[1];
                    }
                    // if (param && param[0].indexOf("sx_dl") == 0) {
                    //     console.log("Language located: " + param[1]);
                    //     // gm_lang = param[1];
                    // }
                }

            }
        });

        sendResponse(true);
    }
});
```